# Redirect using htaccess is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using the following code to redirect all `sitename.com/en/` insider links to `sitename.com/ar/` corresponding ones:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule   ^en/(.*)?$  /ar/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it is not working. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the RewriteCond lines. They are telling that the filename requested must not be a directory or a file.

Comment: @fsabai I tried to remove the RewriteCond lines, but it didn't work